# How to unlock device and keyboard from broadcast receiver in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am making an app in which i want to send some kind of sms alert when user presses some certain combination of volume key. I receive volume key event in a broadcast receiver it works fine when device and keypad unlocked, but when device is locked (Screen off) volume key event not working. I tried this code inside my broadcast receiver's onReceive() method

```
private void wakeUpScreenAndRelaeseLock(Context context)
{
     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
     wakeLock.acquire();

     KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
     KeyguardLock keyguardLock =  keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
     keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
     wakeLock.release();
}
```

also i have added these two permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

please help me to figure out this problem.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If device is in deep sleep volume key presses do not wake it up so you wont receive broadcast notification. You cant do nothing about it, this behaviour is the point of deep sleep.

To achieve what you want your applications has to hold at least partial wake lock.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but when we play a music player in background and device is locked we can able to volume up/down similar thing happens in my app how can i achieve this?

Comment: When music is playing in background device is not in deep sleep - music player is holding a wake lock.